# Game with turns, need a way to receive a fuction's return in another turn

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I'm making a game where I can gather resources or build when I send Workers, but I can't think of a way to receive those resources or finish building depending on the turn and the time(turns) it takes to finish those actions.

I've already made a Worker class, and it has a method to gather and it gives a random value that I save in a Player class. Also, my Game class keeps track of the turn I and the computers are.

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self, player = None):
        self.player = player
        self.turn = 1

class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.workers = [Worker(), Worker(), Worker()]
        self.resourcers = 0

class Worker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hp = 100

    def gather(self):
        return randint(MIN_CANTIDAD_RECURSO, MAX_CANTIDAD_RECURSO)


player = Player()
game = Game()
game.player = player
for worker in player.workers:
    player.resources += worker.gather

game.turn +=1
```

Gathering should give the result the next turn and build should give it depending on the building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a general sense, you store the values you need in the relevant object and pass them as parameters to whatever method requires those values. For example, you would need to store the turn duration of an action in the return value of that action, e.g in `class Worker`

```
def gather(self):
    # Some code that determines gather_value and duration...
    return [gather_value, duration]
```

and then the resource usage would look something like

```
def use_gather(gather, turn): # Pass in (return value from gather, game.turn)
    # Use parameters...
```

With such a vague question, it's hard to say anything more.

Comment: I would like to store the data of the pending actions after I execute an action, in this format ['gather', 'gold', 1] where the last value is the turn I executed the action. So when the game state(turn) changes I would like to get the value of that action. In essense I want to connect the turn when I executed a fuction and the game turn.